# Probability of duplicate free sample of iid discrete random sample

Tags: probability, combinatorics, reference-request

Let $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ be independent identically distributed discrete random variables. I am interested in computing the probability of the event that the sample is duplicate free:
$$
     \mathbb{P}\left( \bigcap_{i<j} \{ X_i \not= X_j\}\right)
$$
in terms of $p_2 = \mathbb{P}\left(X_1 = X_2\right)$, $p_3=\mathbb{P}\left(X_1 = X_2 = X_3\right)$, ..., $p_n = \mathbb{P}\left(X_1 = X_2 = X_3=\ldots=X_n\right)$.

**Special case**
If $X_k$ are uniformly distributed with the size of the sample space being $d$, this is a classic [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) with the answer:
$$
    \mathbb{P}\left( \bigcap_{i<j} \{ X_i \not= X_j\}\right) = \frac{n!}{d^n} \binom{d}{n} = \sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{s(n,k)}{d^{n-k}}
$$
where $s(n,k)$ denotes the Stirling number of the first kind.

**Motivation**
Consider [IEEE floating point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) with mantissa $m$ encoded as $d$-tuple of *significant* binary digits (i.e. the first bit is always 1), and integer binary exponent $e$. For a random real $0<x<1$, bits are iid Bernoulli(1/2) random variables, and $-e$ is a Geometric(1/2) random variable. I am interested in computing the probability of the size $n$ sample having a duplicate.

**My approach**
Applying inclusion-exclusion principle, the complementary probability is 
$$
  \sum_{i<j} \mathbb{P}\left(X_i = X_j\right) - \sum_{i<j,i<p<q} \mathbb{P}\left(X_i = X_j, X_p=X_q\right)+\ldots = \\ \binom{n}{2} p_2 - 3 \binom{n}{4} p_2^2 - 2 \binom{n}{3} p_3 + \ldots
$$

Solutions, ideas, references are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference solving the birthday problem for arbitrary distribution of birthdays is

> Shigeru Mase, "[*Approximations to the birthday problem with unequal occurrence probabilities and their application to the surname problem in Japan*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00050700)," Ann. Inst. Statist. Math., vol. 44, no. 3, pp. 379-499 (1992).

It uses quite  a neat argument involving generating functions. First, note that
$$
   r_n := \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{1\leqslant i<j \leqslant n} \{X_i \not= X_j\}\right) = n! \sum_{1 \leqslant i_1 < i_2 < \ldots < i_{n-1} < i_n \leqslant n} \pi_{i_1} \pi_{i_2} \cdots \pi_{i_{n}} = n! [t^n] \prod_{k \geqslant 1} \left(1 + \pi_k t\right)
$$
where $\pi_k = \mathbb{P}(X=k)$. Therefore 
$$
     1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{r_n}{n!} t^n = \prod_{k \geqslant 1} \left(1 + \pi_k t\right) = \exp\left( \sum_{k \geqslant 1} \log\left(1+\pi_k t\right)\right) = \exp\left( \sum_{s=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{s-1}}{s} t^s \sum_{k \geqslant 1} \pi_k^s\right) = \exp\left( 1 + \sum_{s=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{s-1}}{s} t^s p_s\right)
$$
This gives the expression for $r_n$ as the [complete Bell polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials):
$$
    r_n = B_n\left(1, -p_2, \ldots, (-1)^{n-1} (n-1)! p_n\right) \tag{1}
$$
In particular, assuming $r_0 =1$ the above result implies the recurrence equation for the non-occurrence probabilities $r_n$:
$$ 
   r_n = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!} p_k r_{n-k} \tag{2}
$$

Large $n$ asymptotics (with $n \cdot \max\limits_{k \geqslant 1} \pi_k$ being small) is also worked out in the article:
$$
   r_n \approx  \exp\left(-\binom{n}{2} p_2 - \binom{n}{3}\left( 3 p_2^2 - 2 p_3 \right) + \cdots \right)
$$